# calculate the area of shape created by custom lines on canvas in android

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, canvas

I am making an app for architecture planning. In that, i want to find the area covered by closed shape drawn by line on canvas by drawline() method. This is the Code.

```
public class CanvasBackground extends View {

public static boolean addPath;
public static flg flag;
public static boolean addLine = false;
public static boolean join = false;
public static boolean isDrawing;
public static int myLine;
public static ArrayList<Line> lines = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();
public Paint paint;
public Context context;
public Canvas canvas;
public ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector;
public Bitmap addBtnBitmap;
public int passed_size;
float scalfactor = 1f;
Button addBtn;
public CanvasBackground(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    paint = new Paint();
    scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new CanvasScale());
    DrawingActivity drawingActivity = new DrawingActivity();
    passed_size = drawingActivity.getCategory();


    setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    this.canvas = canvas;
    canvas.save();
    //add Button Select

    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawPaint(paint);

    DrawingZoomingCanvas(canvas);
    DrawingLine(canvas);


    canvas.restore();
    Log.e("OnDraw >>>", "CALLING");
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (addLine) {
                if (lines.size() != 0) {
                    Line current = lines.get(lines.size() - 1);

                    lines.add(new Line(current.stopX, current.stopY, myLine));


                } else {

                    lines.add(new Line(event.getX(), event.getY(), myLine));
                }


                isDrawing = true;
                addLine = false;
            }

            if (addPath) {
                Path path = new Path();
                path.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                paths.add(path);
                isDrawing = true;
                addPath = false;
            }
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (isDrawing) {
                if (lines.size() > 0 && flg.ADDLINE == flag) {
                    Line current = lines.get(lines.size() - 1);
                    current.stopX = event.getX();
                    current.stopY = event.getY();
                } else if (paths.size() > 0 && flg.ADDPATH == flag) {
                    Path path = paths.get(paths.size() - 1);
                    path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                }
                invalidate();
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (isDrawing) {
                if (lines.size() > 0 && flg.ADDLINE == flag) {
                    Line current = lines.get(lines.size() - 1);
                    current.stopX = event.getX();
                    current.stopY = event.getY();
                }
                invalidate();
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    //scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

    Log.e("OnTouch >>>", "CALLING " + isDrawing + " >> " + event.getX() + " >> " + event.getY() + ">>" + event.getAction());
    return true;
}

//drawing a line
private void DrawingLine(Canvas canvas) {
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    for (Line l : lines) {
        canvas.drawLine(l.startX, l.startY, l.stopX, l.stopY, paint);
        canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(l.getSize()), l.startX, l.startY, paint);
    }
    for (Path l : paths) {
        canvas.drawPath(l, paint);
    }
    if (flg.JOIN == flag) {
        Line first = lines.get(0);
        Line last = lines.get(lines.size() - 1);
        Log.e("FL", "First:-" + first.startX + first.startY + "Last" + last.stopX + last.stopY);
        canvas.drawLine(first.startX, first.startY, last.stopX, last.stopY, paint);
        canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(myLine), last.stopX, last.stopY, paint);
        invalidate();
        isDrawing = true;

    }
    setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("CALL CLICK", "vv" + v.getId());
        }
    });

}

//drawing Matrix Canvas With Zoom
private void DrawingZoomingCanvas(Canvas canvas) {
    //drawing Matarix
    canvas.translate(scalfactor * 10, scalfactor * 10);
    canvas.scale(scalfactor, scalfactor);
    paint.setColor(Color.rgb(220, 220, 220));
    for (int i = 0; i <= canvas.getHeight() * scalfactor; i += 10) {
        canvas.drawLine(i, 0, i, canvas.getHeight(), paint);
        canvas.drawLine(0, i, canvas.getWidth(), i, paint);
    }
}

public void join_line() {

    Line first = lines.get(0);
    Line last = lines.get(lines.size() - 1);
    Log.e("FL", "First:-" + first.startX + first.startY + "Last" + last.stopX + last.stopY);
    canvas.drawLine(first.startX, first.startY, last.stopX, last.stopY, paint);
    invalidate();
    isDrawing = true;

}

public enum flg {ADDLINE, ADDPATH, JOIN}

private class CanvasScale extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        scalfactor *= scaleGestureDetector.getScaleFactor();
        scalfactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scalfactor, 10.0f));
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}

}
```

This is the Activity.

```
public class DrawingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public int line_size;
CanvasBackground canvasBackground;
LinearLayout linearLayoutV, linearLayoutH;
Button addBtn, confirmBtn, clearBtn, addPath, joinbtn;
Context context = DrawingActivity.this;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams wrap_content_layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    canvasBackground = new CanvasBackground(context);

    //Main Layout Liner
    linearLayoutV = new LinearLayout(context);
    linearLayoutV.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    linearLayoutH = new LinearLayout(context);
    linearLayoutH.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    linearLayoutH.setWeightSum(4);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(10, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.weight = 1;


    //add Line Button
    addBtn = new Button(context);
    addBtn.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    addBtn.setText("Line+");
    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CanvasBackground.addLine = true;
            CanvasBackground.flag = CanvasBackground.flg.ADDLINE;

            //**************** SET LENGTH
            AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder1.setMessage("Set the length of line");
            builder1.setCancelable(true);
            final EditText input = new EditText(DrawingActivity.this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            input.setLayoutParams(lp);
            builder1.setView(input);

            builder1.setPositiveButton(
                    "Done",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            line_size = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());
                            Log.e("size", String.valueOf(getCategory()));
                            CanvasBackground.myLine = line_size;
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            builder1.setNegativeButton(
                    "Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
            alert11.show();
        }
    });
    linearLayoutH.addView(addBtn);
    // join last button
    joinbtn = new Button(context);
    joinbtn.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    joinbtn.setText("Join");
    joinbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CanvasBackground.flag = CanvasBackground.flg.JOIN;

            v.invalidate();
            //**************** SET LENGTH
            AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder1.setMessage("Set the length of line");
            builder1.setCancelable(true);
            final EditText input = new EditText(DrawingActivity.this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            input.setLayoutParams(lp);
            builder1.setView(input);

            builder1.setPositiveButton(
                    "Done",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            line_size = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());
                            Log.e("size", String.valueOf(getCategory()));
                            CanvasBackground.myLine = line_size;
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            builder1.setNegativeButton(
                    "Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
            alert11.show();

        }
    });
    linearLayoutH.addView(joinbtn);

    //add Line Button
    addPath = new Button(context);
    addPath.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    addPath.setText("Path+");
    addPath.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CanvasBackground.addPath = true;
            CanvasBackground.flag = CanvasBackground.flg.ADDPATH;
        }
    });
    linearLayoutH.addView(addPath);



    //add Confirm Button
    confirmBtn = new Button(context);
    confirmBtn.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    confirmBtn.setText("Ok");
    confirmBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CanvasBackground.isDrawing = false;
        }
    });
    linearLayoutH.addView(confirmBtn);
    linearLayoutV.addView(linearLayoutH);


    linearLayoutV.addView(canvasBackground);

    setContentView(linearLayoutV);
}

public int getCategory() {
    return line_size;
}

}
```

This is the whole code. Please help me.

Comment: do you know the formula to calculate the area of a shape? If you do - convert it to Java. If you don't - first find it, and then convert.

Comment: also you may use search to find ready solutions.

Comment: you are absolutely right. but there is not fixed which shape will be drawn.

Comment: there is universal formula for any shape

Answer (score 1):

Ya you can first validate the shape formed by the user on touch is close by observing the start and end coordinates. Once if the shape is closed. It forms a regular polygon.

For a regular polygon.

1. Find the perimeter of the polygon (permiter = summation of all side length)
2. Then find the apothem of the polygon ( apothem = length of sides / 2tan(180/no of sides))
3. Them find the area using the perimeter and the apothem.(Area = (area * perimeter)/2)

Also refer this link for more info on steps in detail.
http://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Area-of-Regular-Polygons

Comment: Welcome The Kishan.. If you find this answer useful. Please do upvote this answer .